# Convert class file to dex file

Tags: android

How to convert class file to dex file in android?
Is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [dx](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/othertools.html#dx).

Comment: hmmmm...dx ? It's one of the tools provided with the SDK.

Comment: I am getting following error when converting class to dex      trouble processing:
class name (com/WebService) does not match path (WebService.class)
...while parsing WebService.class
...while processing WebService.class
1 warning

Comment: This looks like you are not in the right folder when launching dx. I think you have to be in the main class dir, not in a subfolder (same kind of use as javac for example)

Answer (score 21):

Invoke "dx" command with "--dex" option like the following.

```
dx --dex --output=<output-file> <input-file>
```

"dx" command is contained in Android SDK. The location of the command varies. Try to search:

```
<SDK-HOME>/platform-tools/
<SDK-HOME>/platforms/<platform>/tools/
```

"dx --dex" can accept some options. For example, "--no-strict" option will skip checking whether path names of input class files match the declared package/class names, so you'll get a different result for WebService.class if you invoke dx with this option. Probably, "--keep-classes" option is useful if you want to use jar files on both Android and Java SE. Without "--keep-classes" option, dx command replaces all .class files in an input jar file with one file named "classes.dex", but with "--keep-classes" option, input .class files also go into the ouput file as well as classes.dex.

```
ex:
  dx --dex --keep-classes --output=output.jar input.jar
```

I read the source code of dx and listed up the command line options with some explanation at the following page.

Usage of dx --dex:

http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.com/2011/03/usage-of-dx-dex-dx-dex.html

Comment: For the records: It's now in <SDK-HOME>/build-tools/<build-tools-version>/

Answer (score 2):

The dalvik docs area includes a [trivial example](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/hello-world.html;hb=HEAD).

**Edit:** Link is dead.  You can find the source tree copy [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/master/docs/hello-world.html), and a formatted version in a mirror [here](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/hello-world.html).

Comment: But in general, it's unlikely that your class file(s) and source file(s) would be in the same directory.  The key is to use "--no-strict" as noted below in @darutk's answer.

Comment: Using a standard Java build layout, the package names in the source files should match the directory structure, and the .class files will end up next to the .java files.  No additional options are necessary.  Depending on your build system, this could be totally automatic or very inconvenient, so "dx" provides some flexibility in how it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

For ANT automatic building:

```
 <property name="dx" value="${android_sdk}/build_tools/18.1.0/dx" />
 <target name="convert_jar_to_dex">
    <apply executable="${dx}" failonerror="true" parallel="true">   
            <arg value="-JXms1024m" />  
            <arg value="-JXss1024k" />  
            <arg value="--dex" />   
            <arg value="--verbose" />   
            <arg value="--no-strict" /> 
            <arg value="--num-threads=4" /> 
            <arg value="--output=${basedir}/bin/output.dex" />  
            <fileset file="${basedir}/input.jar"/>  
    </apply>
 </target>
```

This is my experience. May it be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

adding more info for darutk answer:

dx command  is contained in Android SDK

example: D:\Android\AndroidSDK\build-tools\23.0.1\

with 23.0.1 is android version

Comment: This seems to be a comment but not an answer.